# how to manage multiple version of python in virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

i have a project developed in python 2.7 and django 1.10. And i have two version of python 3.11 and 2.7.now i am trying to create virtual environment but unable to

1- i have tried this -

```
C:\Experiment projects\Django project\project1>virtualenv -p C:\Python27 myenv
RuntimeError: failed to query C:\Python27 with code 13 err: 'Access is denied'
```

I have given full right to the C:\python27 to all users

2- And

```
C:\Experiment projects\Django project\project1>Python -m venv myenv

C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named venv
```

Comment: put "python --version" in your terminal and make sure it is detecting python in your terminal.

Comment: yes it detecting but same problem - Python 2.7.1

Comment: Ok, Virtual environment in Python is added after Python 3.3 version. You may install "pip install virtualenv" and create virtual environment using "virtualenv myenv"

But I suggest to use latest version Python.

Comment: `virtualenv -p C:\Python27\python.exe myenv` I.e. point `-p` to python executable, not to a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 2 Python Code, I suggest you to remove all Python and have latest Python Version in your system.
Note: While installing Python, Please enable to add **Path** in `Environment Variable`

For your issue, Since you are using Python 2.7.1, Creating Virtual Enviornment is not possible with the command `python -m venv myenv`. It is available after Python 3.3.

If your system provide Python 2.7.1 when you use **python --version**
You may follow the step given below

```
pip install virtualenv

virtualenv myenv
```

Step 2:

Since you have multiple python version, Find the path of the Python 3.11.5 exe file.
You may use command `where python` and once your get the path of the exe file.
You can now use it like `C:\path\to\python3.11.5.exe -m venv myenv`
Replace the path with what you get.

Comment: Ap, its created but not for python 2.7 it is for 3.11

Comment: (myenv) C:\Experiment projects\Django project\project1\myenv\Scripts>python --version
Python 3.11.5

Comment: I have added Step 2 in my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Issue 2:
Error: C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named venv

This happens because the venv module is not available in Python 2.7.
The venv is included in Python 3 versions.

try use **[virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** for python 2.7.

Comment: thank you for answer. I am going to try it.